# SwiftUI Error Regarding Publishing Changes from Background Thread

Tags: swiftui

I am not quite sure how to fix an error that appears three times in my View Model:

```
import SwiftUI

class GHViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible())
    ]
    
    @Published var followers: [Follower] = []
    @Published var page = 1
    @Published var user: User = PlaceholderData.user
    @Published var networkError: GFError = .invalidURL
    @Published var shouldShowNetworkError = false
    @Published var shouldShowFollowerDetails = false
    
    func getFollowers(userID: String) {
        NetworkManager.shared.getFollowers(for: userID, page: self.page) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let followers):
                if !followers.isEmpty {
                    self.followers += followers
                    print("**** GHViewModel -> FollowersScreen has retrieved the followers.  I see \(self.followers.count) followers for this user.")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                self.shouldShowNetworkError = true
                self.networkError = error
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getFollowerDetails(userID: String) {
        NetworkManager.shared.getUserInfo(for: userID) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let ghUser):
                self.user = ghUser
                self.shouldShowFollowerDetails = true
            case .failure(let error):
                self.shouldShowNetworkError = true
                self.networkError = error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The 3 warnings are happening at:

```
@Published var followers: [Follower] = []
```

and..

```
case .success(let ghUser):
  self.user = ghUser
  self.shouldShowFollowerDetails = true
```

What is this error actually saying?  I suppose it's suggesting that I should be using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { // code here }
```

around the code that's generating the warnings?

Please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is telling your to use `DispatchQueue.main.async`.  Remember, network calls are asynchoronous. You don't know when you are getting a response, so they are automatically performed on a background thread, but you always need to update your data that is being displayed on your main thread. Therefore,  every time you hit `.success`, you need to update the variables on the main thread by enclosing the updates in `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

```
        case .success(let followers):
            if !followers.isEmpty {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.followers += followers
                    print("**** GHViewModel -> FollowersScreen has retrieved the followers.  I see \(self.followers.count) followers for this user.")
                }
            }
```

and

```
case .success(let ghUser):
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.user = ghUser
      self.shouldShowFollowerDetails = true
  }
```

I suspect the `@Published` error will go away as I suspect that is thrown due to the other issues.